# Codeship and PHPunit selenium class not loaded

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, codeship

I am using Codeship to run some PHPUnit tests for WordPress.

Tests written with `WP_UnitTestCase` work fine.

```
class ActionHookTests extends WP_UnitTestCase {
    function test_things() {
        // this runs fine
    }
}
```

However, my selenium tests won't run:

```
class TestIntegration extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase {
    function test_things() {
        // this throws an error
    }
}
```

The following error is thrown in Codeship:

**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase' not found**

However, the tests run fine on my local machine.

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `composer install?`

`composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction`

https://codeship.com/documentation/languages/php/